# How to work with related database from passed data via Axios in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Project Laravel + Vue. I'm very beginner with js.
I'm getting my `preferredShares:[]` using Axios like

```
axios
    .get('/company/' + encodeURIComponent(this.company_id) + '/preferredShares')
    .then(response => (this.preferredShares = response.data))
```

Explaining method: Using loop for each `equity` in `preferredShares`. So each `equity` has related table `grants` and for each `grant` in `grants` I need to find `sum(grant.shares_amount)` and than use as variable. My code will explain the problem:

```
const preferenceShares = this.preferredShares.reduce((sum, equity) => {

                // 1) How to connect with related database??
                grants = equity.grants 
                totalIssued = grants.reduce((sum, grant) => {
                    return sum + grant.shares_amount
                }, 0)

                //2) need to add this value to equity array
                equity.push(totalIssued)

                // somehow return should be this
                return finalValue =  equity.totalIssued

        }, 0)
        return preferenceShares
```

Comment: Can you please provide some mock data for the response? That will help me help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close.

```
const total = preferredShares.reduce((sum, equity) => {

    const totalIssued = equity.grants.reduce((sum2, grant) => {
        return sum2 + grant.shares_amount
    }, 0)

    return sum + totalIssued;

}, 0);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sa94myve/